# Is a word like 'thx' a contraction or abbreviation?

Tags: abbreviations, contractions

Putting aside that the use of 'thx' is bad, and it isn't really a word.  *Would 'thx' be considered a contraction or abbreviation?*

[**Contraction**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_(grammar)): a shortened version of the written and spoken forms of a word, syllable, or word group, created by omission of internal letters (actually, sounds).

The page also states that a contraction "shouldn't be confused with an abbreviation or acronym.  My logic says that it would be an abbreviation since a contraction would also change the phonetic version of the word while an abbreviation does not.

Comment: Your logic is correct.

Comment: I suggest it is a contraction of the phonetic, 'thanx'.  Note that some people consider this to be a thank you followed by a kiss. Kisses are commonly appended to a missive in the form of a letter 'X'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abbreviation. Rather like "Xmas", "thx" is a written, not a spoken, shorthand. The word is still pronounced "Thanks".

Answer (score 1):

Thx is an abbreviation of "thanks".  The 'x' at the end replaces the 's', and when spoken aloud, sounds the same as the original word.

The word "thanks", is actually a plural of "thank you", so if you were given "many thanks", you were given many "thank yous".

Comment: Small nitpick, but the "x" replaces the "ks", same as in ["thanx"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=thanx).